# ASA5505: Add remote AnyConnect subnet routing over site-to-site VPN // mixed ASA 8.4 .8.2 firmware

Tags: routing, vpn

**Backstory**: I have a site to site VPN from my ASA with 9.x firmware to a remote ASA with 8.2 firmware (NOT managed by me). We got the tunnel up and running quite a while ago, I ended up having to specifically add an ACL for ICMP.

The **Problem**: The other end provides AnyConnect SSL VPN connectivity and users connecting to the SSL VPN need access to my end of the site to site VPN, so I added to the existing subnets.

The **Error**:Running packet tracer from 10.10.10.5 destination: 192.168.99.5
I get:

```
VPN: Type -
VPN
Subtype -
encrypt
Action -
DROP
```

RESULT: The packet is dropped
INFO: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule

**Networking info**:

- My site=10.10.10.0/24
- Other site=10.1.0.0/16
- SSL VPN=192.168.99.0/24

The **changes that I've made** (added):

```
access-list VPN_ACCESS extended permit icmp 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.0
access-list VPN_ACCESS extended permit ip 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.0
```

And based upon this rule:

```
nat (inside,outside) source static LocalLAN LocalLAN destination static DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
```

I also added added:

```
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 network-object object REMOTESSLVPN

object network REMOTESSLVPN  subnet 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.0
```

......

So, am I crazy, or shouldn't that work? What could I be missing? I recall that the initial setup between the sub 8.2 and the >8.3 firmware was a lot of trouble, but this should be simple. Does anyone have any insight?

EDIT:
Here's the detailed packet trace from cli:

```
(config)# packet-tracer input inside tcp 10.10.10.0 80 192.168.99.0 $

Phase: 1
Type: ROUTE-LOOKUP
Subtype: input
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
in   0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         outside

Phase: 2
Type: UN-NAT
Subtype: static
Result: ALLOW
Config:
nat (inside,outside) source static LocalLAN LocalLAN destination static > > DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
Additional Information:
NAT divert to egress interface outside
Untranslate 192.168.99.0/80 to 192.168.99.0/80

Result:
input-interface: inside
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: outside
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (sp-security-failed) Slowpath security checks failed
```

Comment: Does the other site allow traffic from your site to the new networks, and vice versa?

Comment: SSL VPN=192.168.99.0/16  ==> I assume this should be /24 ? And as Ron mentioned, does the ACL on your inside interface allow the traffic ?

Comment: Can you provide output of the same packet-tracer command but this time with the "detailed" option please?

Comment: @Ron Maupin, Yes, the other end added an ACL, the other tech says that his packet tracer shows success.

Comment: @hertitu yes, thank you, it is /24, I fixed it. Ah... as far as ACLs, only the one's I've noted above. Oddly enough, they don't show up in my asdm.

Adding the detailed packet trace

Comment: Also, if I attempt to add anything to the inside interface, the implicit permit rule is removed and everybody is SOL. I can't imagine that needs to be changed--or should be changed, for that matter.

Comment: You cannot run the packet tracer with network addresses. Please run it again with e.g. .5 as you did initially

Comment: Your ACL VPN_ACCESS does not need the first `icmp` statement, that's already included in `ip`.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

On the ASA running the version 8.2 code, there are a few potential issues. The first is the SSL VPN could be setup for split tunneling and they would need to add your subnet in the split tunnel list.

Second is the SSL VPN connects to the outside interface as well as your site to site VPN. They will need to permit hair pinning on the outside interface by issuing this command on the remote ASA

`same-security-traffic permit intra-interface`.

The third is the NAT exemption. They may need to do something like this on the remote ASA

`static (outside,outside) 192.168.99.0 192.168.99.0 netmask 255.255.255.0`.

If this doesn't work I would verify the remote end's crypto ACL and make sure the SSL VPN subnet is specified and that routing to the SSL VPN subnet is added to your router.

Josh

Comment: While all of this is correct, it does not explain the drop action in the packet tracer.

Comment: ...nvm, sh routes doesn't show routes for the other end either way. 
I'll check with the other tech.

Comment: Wait, you make a good point about the NAT exemption, I think I had to do something similar. I'll let you know.

Comment: Yep, other end is u-turning correctly. I'm still convinced that this is on my end given the packet tracer output. I tried rebooting my firewall hoping that re-establishing the vpn on boot would allow the second subnet via the vpn acl

Comment: OK, just noticed that every time I try to ping the 192.168.99.x subnet, I get this in the logs every time, can someone translate what it means?

•Tunnel Manager dispatching a KEY_ACQUIRE message to IKEv1. Map Tag = outside_map. Map Sequence Number = 1.
•IKEv2 Doesn't have a proposal specified
•Group = 206.x.x.x, IP = 206.x.x.x, IKE Initiator: New Phase 2, Intf outside, IKE Peer 206.x.x.x local Proxy Address 10.10.10.0, remote Proxy Address 192.168.99.0, Crypto map (outside_map)
•Group = 206.x.x.x IP = 206.x.x.x, Received non-routine Notify message: Invalid ID info (18)

Comment: @bittrekker It sounds like it is trying to bring up a phase 2 sa for the 192.168.99.0/24 and can't. Normally because of the crypto ACL. Run this packet-tracer command and post the ouput: `packet-tracer input inside tcp 10.10.10.1 80 192.168.99.1 80 detailed`. (Note: you may need to run the packet-tracer command twice for the phase 2 sa to come up. After you run that get the output for `show crypto ipsec sa` and please post. Also try removing this command from your crypto ACL since it isn't needed `access-list VPN_ACCESS extended permit icmp 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.0`.